# gitlab-reconfigure blocked on redis after reinstalling gitlab on ubuntu 18.04.4LTS

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce

This is the third time I install gitlab on server and never had issues before.

I decide to reinstall gitlab-ce ( 12.10.0 ) after dealing with issues on 12.9.0.

Before installing the new version, I had ensured that all gitlab files where removed and reboot the server.

Step1: Uninstall gitlab 12.9.0

```
# gitlab-ctl stop
# gitlab-ctl uninstall
# apt-get remove --purge gitlab-ce
# find / -iname "gitlab" then try to remove all outputed files
# init 6
```

Step 2: Fresh install gitlab 12.10.0

```
# apt-get update
# apt-get install gitlab-ce=12.10.0-ce.0
```

Then I updated my /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb file according to my server config.

Finally, I executed:

```
gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

The processes was blocked on :

**ruby_block[wait for redis service socket] action run**

Any solutions ?

Comment: Did you solve this in he meantime? Have the exact same problem but no solution anywhere. [This](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/gitlab-ce-rhel7-reconfigure-get-stuck-on-first-reconfigure/36422/1) has more additional information but no solution either.

Comment: Yes but I didn't remember exactly what I've done.. Have a look at [Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/711566/redis-server-does-not-create-socket-file)

Comment: Had the same Problem. This resolved it for me: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/common_installation_problems/#reconfigure-freezes-at-ruby_blocksupervise_redis_sleep-action-run

Answer (score 37):

The link provided by Manuel Richarz indicated there might be different lines upon which the installation may hang, one of them being the `ruby_block[wait for redis service socket] action run` line your question is about.

Their proposed solution is to open a new terminal and run:

```
systemctl restart gitlab-runsvdir.service
```

This worked for me for the `ruby_block[wait for logrotate service socket] action run` line.

Comment: Saved me almost two hours of waiting on `ruby_block[wait for logrotate service socket] action run`

Comment: Don't know if it was relevant but I deleted /var/opt/gitlab/redis/dump.rdb before restarting gitlab-runsvdir, based on this comment : https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/-/issues/293#note_92244520

Answer (score 10):

7 years later, and the `systemctl restart gitlab-runsvdir.service` command in a secondary terminal did the trick quite well.
Directly after executing this command, install no longer hangs and continued and finished all well.