# Installing gitlab on Ubuntu 22.04 docker :: "warning: logrotate: unable to open supervise/ok: file does not exist"

Tags: gitlab, logrotate, gitlab-ce, ubuntu-22.04

I am following this tutorial for setting up the gitlab on Ubuntu 22.04 -- https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-gitlab-ce-on-ubuntu-linux/

While running the gitlab package using this command

`# gitlab-ctl reconfigure`

the process is stuck on this step --

`* ruby_block[wait for logrotate service socket] action run`

Getting following output on running the `# gitlab-ctl status` and `# gitlab-ctl stop` command --

`warning: logrotate: unable to open supervise/ok: file does not exist`

How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if [restarting gitlab-runsvdir.service](https://support.websoft9.com/docs/gitlab/admin-services.html), as shown here, would help.

Maybe, as [commented here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67536216/6309), you would need to delete `/var/opt/gitlab/redis/dump.rdb` first.

The alternative is to use a [GitLab-CE Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce), which would not have any of those issues (since everything is already installed in said image).

Comment: Have to say that I'm having exactly the same problem in the GitLab-CE Docker image :(

Comment: @JohnY With which version of GitLab?

Comment: This started after the Docker container auto-upgraded to 15.0. Forcing it back down to 14.10.3 doesn't resolve the problem.